# How the method getDefaultToolkit works in java?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

I'm learning Java, particularly how to make GUIs. I don't understand how the method getDefaultToolkit works, because this method is abstract and I have been looking in the API and it seems that no class inherits from Toolkit because. In some classes it appears the "Direct Known Subclasses" section but in the class Toolkit it doesn't appear.

Thanks!

Comment: No answer here but the vast majority of Java development has long since moved away from Swing and AWT.  Learning more about Java is fine but I'd encourage you look in other areas.

Comment: @user16320675 "it" here refers to `Toolkit`, which is in fact abstract: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html

Comment: "this method is abstract..." I think you mean that the `Toolkit` class is abstract. The `getDefaultToolkit()` method is not.

Comment: @user16320675 Yes, `getDefaultToolkit()` is static. I think the OP mistyped since the rest of his question clearly refers to the `Toolkit` class which is not abstract. (Notice how I avoid the word "it" here to be entirely clear about what thing I'm talking about.)

Comment: According to the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getDefaultToolkit()), `getDefaultToolkit` is NOT `abstract`, `public static Toolkit getDefaultToolkit()`.  This is a "factory" style method, whose responsibility it is, is to load the platform specific implementation of the `Toolkit`

Answer (score 1):

The **class** [Toolkit](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Toolkit.html) is abstract, the method `getDefaultToolkit()` is not abstract, it is even static. So you absolutely do not need a specific subclass to invoke it, to the contrary. As the method is static, the "correct" way to invoke it is by simply calling `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()`; thus there is no need at all for any known subclass to implement anything here.

That is all there is to this.

Well: the fact that the OP couldn't find any subclass of Toolkit is based on misconception: not every class that gets shipped with Standard Java is documented.

Answer (score 0):

> I have been looking in the API and it seems that no class inherits from Toolkit because. In some classes it appears the "Direct Known Subclasses" section but in the class Toolkit it doesn't appear.

You have the right idea. There is some class that `extends Toolkit` and implements all of the necessary methods. This class is not published as part of the public API. This means that the exact name of this class is hidden. Honestly those details aren't really important. That's the whole point of inheritance and polymorphism.

`getDefaultToolkit()` creates an instance of this class and returns it.

Comment: @user16320675 What do you mean?

Comment: @user16320675 I still don't understand about which "that" you are referring to when you say "I wonder if that works".

Comment: @user16320675 Besides, we already clarified that we aren't actually talking about any abstract methods here.

Comment: @user16320675 While that is true, the OP does not mention any methods that are actually abstract. But this is besides the point. What do you mean by "I wonder if that works"? Or is your question no longer relevant?